# adding custom code to jquery answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form which inputs values like this

```
 <div class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container" id="frm_field_102_container">

<label class="frm_primary_label" for="field_lyhhho">test
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
</label>

<input type="text" value="" name="item_meta[102]" id="field_lyhhho">    
</div>
```

Is there a way to change the input type with jquery to

```
   <input type="text" value="" name="item_meta[91]" id="field_ljuq4c"
  data-slider="true" data-slider-range="100,500" data-slider-step="100" data-slider-snap="true">
```

I basically want to add this to the input type

```
 data-slider="true" data-slider-range="100,500" data-slider-step="100" data-slider-snap="true
```

I have tried everything i can think of to just add that part

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Does this do it? `$(function() {
   $("#field_lyhhho")
    .data("slider",true)
    .data("slider-range","100,500")
    .data("slider-step","100")
    .data("slider-snap",true);
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this useing Jquery `attr` to add or edit `attribute`

```
$('#field_lyhhho').attr('name',"item_meta[91]");
$('#field_lyhhho').attr('data-slider',true);
$('#field_lyhhho').attr('data-slider-range',"100,500");
$('#field_lyhhho').attr('data-slider-step',"100");
$('#field_lyhhho').attr('data-slider-snap',true);
```